# How to get the selected item index on a .NET ComboBox control?

Tags: vb.net, combobox, indexing, selecteditem

I have a `ComboBox` setup with 4 items, with indexes ranging from 0 to 3.

Later in my code, I need to do a certain event depending on what is selected. To do this I thought about comparing what the index of the selected `ComboBox` item is, because integer comparison is faster than strings, right?

How can I get the index of the selected item?

Comment: Why are you worried about performance when you have a list of four items?

Comment: Is it not a good thing to think about performance everywhere? Besides, the number of items can be changed, depends on what the user sets it as.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ComboBox has a [SelectedIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindex.aspx) property.

```
myComboBox.SelectedIndex
```

Regarding comparison:
If you're not doing millions of comparisons then this "optimization" wouldn't help you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that integer comparison is always faster than string comparison?

Depends how long the strings your comparing are... If you compare two strings that each only have one character then its a simple byte-wise AND operation which may be faster than comparing a 4 byte integer value.

Comment: Each string is 32 bytes long exactly.